# Raised paver patio - does it need to be replaced?

Tags: patio

hoping for some help here. Can’t tell if salesman are trying to hose for me for cash.

This patio was built 3 years ago, right before I bought my house. Prior inspector (not mine) said there may need to be a 'vapor barrier' between the patio and house. My inspector said everything was perfectly fine. So I bought the house. Now, later on - I couldn't get the thought of if this patio had been incorrectly installed off my mind.

I’m being told that if I don’t remove the patio, it will cause structural damage to my house eventually because it was:

1. sealed to house without siding being taken off
2. sealed to wall and not foundation
3. there isn’t a retaining wall on the side by house to hold the load

Anyone have any insight on this? It’ll cost me 30k or so to do the removal and rebuild. Hoping it doesn’t need to be done. I will also add that the patio is sloped so that water drains and doesn't build on the patio.

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE - here is what is under when I take a brick out of the patio, by the side of house.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it causing any problem?  water stains on the inside of the house/basement?  Any movement?

Comment: It's not causing problems at the moment. no water stains. Just worried and want to ensure I am proactive if this is absolutely going to be an issue. Also want to make sure I am not being scammed though...

Comment: How was the patio "sealed" to the house wall? What "sealant" was used? Sure, you probably don't know, but providing some pics might help someone get you an answer. Remember, the inspector's job (especially if _you_ paid him, not the seller) is to give you an unbiased opinion on the state of the property, while a salesman's job is to _sell_ you something. Get 2 or 3 more patio companies and a couple of general contractors in and get a consensus opinion on whether or not it's really a problem.

Comment: Great question - I guess it wasn’t really ‘sealed’. The ‘sealant’ is just polymeric sand. You can see it in the last pic I included - the pavers running along the composite wood siding.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how this would cause all those catastrophic problems.  You aren't accumulating excess water against the house if it is properly sloped and vinyl siding is going to serve as a partial barrier.  **IF** you started seeing problems, the beauty of a paver patio is you can remove individual pavers and rework the area along the house.  Not anywhere near $30k.  And the salesman knows this.

Comment: Just to be clear - siding is composite wood, unsure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

> "there isn’t a retaining wall on the side by house to hold the load"

That's the tattletale statement that tells me the salesman is full of bullspit.

With just a paver removed, no one really knows what's there. It's speculation.

The salesman is trying to brew fear in your head in hopes you agree to buy what he is selling.

Tell him "Thank you for your opinion."  and move on.

If no signs of problems exist, it's because there isn't any problems. After 3 years something should have started to manifest it's self.

Comment: Looks to me like the patio was built right up against the now-below-grade siding...

Comment: @Huesmann you are correct. it's build right up against the siding.

Comment: Well that's a problem.

Comment: how big of a problem? @Huesmann